# How to migrate a few directories to another TFS server

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

There is an issue : we have a few directories in `TFS` that could be migrated to the another `TFS` server. Are there are any good tools to perform it ? But we have the additional requirement - sometimes we need to merge code from source `TFS` to new `TFS`.

Comment: You want to migrate the source code from VSO to a on-premise TFS?

Comment: vice versa, from TFS to VSO, but with possibility make simple merge changes in TFS to VSO

Answer (score 2):

To migrate certain directories, you need to choose to use TFS Integration Tool: https://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/

In it, it is possible to select path you would like to migrate.

[image]

Comment: That, however will not work if the target directory is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft recommends for this kind of migration [OpsHub](https://www.visualstudio.com/get-started/setup/migrate-team-projects-vs#what_data).

For basic scenarios you can try [OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/28a90a17-d00c-4660-b7ae-42d58315ccf2).

Comment: But can i migrate only certain directories from `TFS` ?

Comment: @DotNetGoose what do you mean with directories? Certain projects? Or parts of a project?